# Having trouble hiding elements and and showing others when div li element selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   Below is my html example
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto right">
     <li class="nav-item dropdown drop-icon">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle "  id="dropdown01" data- 
          toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
           expanded="false">Menu</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mission" 
            class="mission">Mission</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact" 
            class="contact">Contact</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#portfolio" 
            class="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </div>

below is my jquery
$(document).ready(() => {
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(() => {
    var change = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.dropdown-item .'+change).show();
    $('.dropdown-item .'+change).siblings().hide();
});
});
```

What i am looking to do is hide all elements on page load and only show certain elemnts when menu item is clicked while making all other elements outside that div go back to being hidden.

Comment: You need to post code that attempts to do what you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the contents you want to show, exclude them from a selection of all items, and hide what's left. You'll also want to specify that you only want to trigger the event on dropdown-toggle class as well:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function () {
    var mine = $(this).siblings().children(".dropdown-item");
    $('.dropdown-item').not(mine).hide();
    mine.show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto right">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown drop-icon">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle "  id="dropdown01" data- 
      toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
      expanded="false">Menu</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mission" 
        class="mission">Mission</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact" 
        class="contact">Contact</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#portfolio" 
        class="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown drop-icon">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle "  id="dropdown02" data- 
      toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
      expanded="false">Foobar</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mission" 
        class="mission">Mission</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact" 
        class="contact">Contact</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#portfolio" 
        class="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You are missing to add `dropdown01` class in the anchor element with class `dropdown-item`. You need to add that class.
2. After adding the class your selector will be `$('.dropdown-item.' + change)` since both the class is in the same element so there will be no space between the class selector.
3. You can use `$('.dropdown-item').hide();` before showing the elements. This will hide all the elements of that class first and show only the elements of the clicked menu in the next line.
4. You need to define a css where it hides all the elements with class `.dropdown-item` on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    var change = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.dropdown-item').hide();
    $('.dropdown-item.' + change).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto right">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown drop-icon">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " id="dropdown01" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Menu1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown01" href="#mission" class="mission">Mission</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown01" href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown01" href="#portfolio" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " id="dropdown02" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Menu2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown02" href="#mission" class="mission">Mission 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown02" href="#contact" class="contact">Contact 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown02" href="#portfolio" class="portfolio">Portfolio 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```